# Show date listing from today onward

Tags: date, entry, grouping

How can I make a list which show the date from today to following 10 days?
Like
Thu, June 25, 2015
Fri, June 26, 2015
Sat, June 27, 2015
Sun, June 28, 2015
Mon, June 29, 2015

And then make entry list under the matching date to entry date.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is your best option.

https://github.com/ehousestudio/dailee_entries

If you can't make that work, I can probably come up with a combination of PHP and template tags that would work. It'd be an ugly template but it would work.

**Edit**

If I were you, I'd fork this and just use it as a base to get the plugin to output how you'd like.

Comment: yeah, maybe be just need to fork that and edit that. thanks for attach this plugin. but still see whether any better answer first. Will try to edit that.

Comment: I tried to use stash achieve that. but failed on the parse problem.
http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/32071/stash-and-date-plugin

Answer (score 1):

First I thought about the [`display_by` parameter](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#display-by), but the user guide says:

> The display_by parameter uses the last unit of time provided that has entries. If you `display_by="day"` then it will show the last day that has entries. If you `display_by="month"` combined with `limit="3"` then it will show the last 3 months with entries, even if these months are not consecutive.

So... I'm not sure it will work.

But there's another option. You should be able to use `+10 days` on [`stop_before`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#stop-before) parameter.

```
{exp:channel:entries [...] start_on="today" stop_before="+10 days" show_future_entries="yes"}
  {date_heading display="daily"}<h1>{entry_date format="%Y %m %d"}</h1>{/date_heading}  
  <h2>{title}</h2>
  {body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Please, try.

Comment: This will show all date with entry.
Let say if 1 of the day i dun have entry and i need the date header as well?
Then on the day it show No entry.